# How do i calculate which value in array has bigger sum on database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array which each one of them have a different sum on database (maybe some of them are empty or there is no record for them)

i need to know which one has bigger sum **THAN ALL THE OTHERS (ON MY ARRAY)** and put that one in $bigger variable, ($bigger = $value)

My try:

```
$new = 0;
$myarray = array('2', '5', '17', '55');

foreach($myarray as $value) {
    $before = intval($new);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(total) AS totals FROM table WHERE id='$value'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $new = intval($result['totals']);

    if ($new > $before){
        $biggest=intval($value);
    }
}
```

but it only shows if the newer one has bigger value than the older one, not bigger than all of them

Any help is appreciated

Comment: by "bigger than all of them" do you mean all of that specific array or the entire rows of your database?

Comment: i mean bigger than all of specific arrays, for example array(5) should be bigger than 2 and 17 and 55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would eliminate the looping altogether and do it like this:

```
$myarray = array('2', '5', '17', '55');
$query = "SELECT SUM(total) AS totals FROM table WHERE id IN (" . implode(', ', $myarray) . ") GROUP BY id ORDER BY totals DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Note that is you want to receive data for all id's in sorted order you can simply remove the `LIMIT` clause, and add a looping to read out each row of the result set.

I would also recommend not using the `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. If you are just learning PHP, you should learn using `mysqli_*` functions, PDO or something that will enjoy support in the future.

You should also learn how to test for failure conditions on your database queries.  My example is a simple one, but production code should test the success/failure of the query and of the fetch operation.

Comment: I was trying `MAX(SUM(total))`, and that wasn't working.  This on the other hand works perfectly! :-)

Comment: thank you mike, if i use $safe_array = mysql_real_escape_string($array); before query is it dangerous to use mysql_query ? because PDO is disabled on server and they wont enable it

Comment: Oh so you are actually getting that array of data passed in from somewhere?  You should absolutely use sanitize it.  You can't pass an array to `mysql_real_escape_string`, you would probably be best do an `$safe_array = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array)` on the input array first.